# A theory of higher limits of (1-)functors, after higher hochschild homology

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories, hochschild-homology

$\newcommand{\Trans}{\mathrm{Trans}}\newcommand{\H}{\mathrm{H}}\newcommand{\HH}{\mathrm{HH}}\newcommand{\Hom}{\mathrm{Hom}}\newcommand{\Mod}{\mathrm{Mod}}$Recently I noticed that one may regard the co/simplicial set computing the co/limit of a diagram as a (many-object, non-abelian) analogue of the Hochschild co/chain complex of an algebra with coefficients in a module. This should lead to a theory of higher co/limits, but in an orthogonal direction to higher category theory.

---

**Motivation in the Abelian Case.** Here's what the Hochschild cochain complex $\HH^*(A;M)$ of an $R$-algebra $A$ with coefficients in a bimodule $M$ looks like:
$$M\to \Hom_{\Mod_R}(A,M)\to\Hom_{\Mod_R}(A\otimes_RA,M)\to\Hom_{\Mod_R}(A\otimes_RA\otimes_RA,M)\to\cdots.$$
Now, take a $\Mod_R$-enriched category $\cal C$ and a functor $D\colon\mathcal{C}^{\mathrm{op}}\times\mathcal{C}\to\Mod_R$, and consider the following cosimplicial abelian group, denoted by $\HH^\bullet(\mathcal{C};D)$:

\begin{align*}
\prod_{A\in\cal C}D(A,A) &\rightrightarrows \prod_{A,B\in\cal C}\Hom_{\Mod_R}(\Hom_{\cal C}(A,B),D(A,B))\\
&\underset{\to}{\rightrightarrows}\prod_{A,B,C\in \cal C}\Hom_{\Mod_R}(\Hom_{\cal C}(A,B)\otimes_R\Hom_{\cal C}(B,C),D(A,C))\\
&\underset{\rightrightarrows}{\rightrightarrows}\cdots
\end{align*}

Under the dual Dold–Kan correspondence, $\HH^\bullet(\mathcal{C};D)$ has an associated cochain complex $\mathsf{C}^*(\mathcal{C};D)$, and when $\mathcal{C}$ has only a single object―that is, when it is an $R$-algebra―it recovers precisely the Hochschild cochain complex defined above.

However, we also have the following isomorphisms:
\begin{align*}
\pi_0\HH^\bullet(\mathcal{C};D) &\cong \H^0(\mathsf{C}^*(\mathcal{C};D))\\
                                &\cong \int_{A\in\mathcal{C}}D(A,A);
\end{align*}
that is: this cochain complex computes the end of $D$ as its zeroth cohomology! Similarly, there are complexes computing the co/limit of a presheaf or functor that are analogous to the Hochschild complex of an $R$-algebra with coefficients in a left or right module.

> **Main Question.** *Have the higher cohomology groups of this complex (which may perhaps be thought of as higher versions of limits and ends) been studied before in the literature, apart from the one-object case? Are them of any use in mathematical practice?*

(As noted below in the comments, the cohomology groups above can be expressed as being the cohomology of certain homotopy coends, but what I'm after here is whether these cohomology groups *themselves* have been used to study other objects of interest, e.g. taking the limit diagram $D$ of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and trying to relate $\pi_{\geq1}(\HH(\mathrm{CRing};D))$ with number-theoretical information about $\mathbb{Z}_p$, or taking $D$ to be the Hom of a one-object groupoid associated to a group $G$ and studying the "higher characteristic classes" $\pi_{\geq1}(\HH(\mathrm{Sets};D))$, this time relating them to group-theoretical information about $G$, and so on.)

---

**Example.** One interesting example is that this complex applied to $D=\Hom(F,G)$ gives a cochain complex $\Trans^*(F,G)$ of transformations between functors $F,G\colon\mathcal{C}\to\Mod_R$. It looks like this:

\begin{align*}
\prod_{A\in\cal C}\Hom_{\mathcal{D}}(F(A),G(A)) &\xrightarrow{d^1} \prod_{A,B\in\cal C}\Hom_{\Mod_R}(\Hom_{\cal C}(A,B),\Hom_{\mathcal{D}}(F(A),G(B)))\\
&\xrightarrow{d^2}\prod_{A,B,C\in \cal C}\Hom_{\Mod_R}(\Hom_{\cal C}(A,B)\otimes_R\Hom_{\cal C}(B,C),\Hom_{\mathcal{D}}(F(A),G(C)))\\
&\xrightarrow{d^3}\cdots.
\end{align*}
Now, this already seems like a very interesting object to consider:

- First, $\Trans^0(F,G)$ recovers [unnatural transformations](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/unnatural+transformation), and $\H^0(\Trans^0(F,G))$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Nat}(F,G)$.
- Second, $\H^{\geq1}(\Trans^*(F,G))$ seems to provide a notion of higher natural transformation that goes in a completely orthogonal direction to higher category theory (perhaps we might call these "sharp transformations" to avoid confusion?)

For example, in classical Hochschild cohomology, we have isomorphisms

\begin{align*}
\HH^1(A;M) &\cong \mathrm{Der}(A,M)/\mathrm{InnDer}(A,M)\\
           &=     \mathrm{OutDer}(A,M)
\end{align*}

identifying the first Hochschild cohomology of $A$ in $M$ with outer derivations. This should give notions of:

- Derivations from $F$ to $G$, defined as $\mathrm{Ker}(d^2)$;
- Inner derivations from $F$ to $G$, defined as $\mathrm{Im}(d^1)$;
- Outer derivations from $F$ to $G$, defined as $\H^1(\Trans^*(F,G))$.

Concretely, here's what a derivation from $F$ to $G$ looks like: it is a family
$$\{\alpha_{A,B}\colon\Hom_C(A,B)\to\Hom_D(F_A,G_B)\}$$
of morphisms of $R$-modules such that we have an equality
$$\alpha_{A,C}(g\circ f)=G(g)\circ\alpha_{A,B}(f)+\alpha_{B,C}(g)\circ F(f)$$
for each $A,B,C\in\mathcal{C}$, each $f\in\Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(A,B)$, and each $g\in\Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(B,C)$.

(We could also write the above equation as
$$\alpha_{A,C}(g\circ f)=g\triangleleft\alpha_{A,B}(f)+\alpha_{B,C}(g)\triangleright f$$
with $g\triangleleft-=G(g)\circ -$ and $-\triangleleft f=-\circ F(f)$ the left and right actions of the bimodule $\Hom_{\mathcal{D}}(F,G)$ on $\mathcal{C}$, to emphasize the similarity with the Leibniz rule for derivations.)

Here are the relevant diagrams, which look a bit like two naturality squares for morphisms $f$ and $g$ glued together side to side:

[image]

---

**Remarks on the non-abelian case.** The above story has an analogue for non-enriched categories, with similar co/simplicial sets (see page 2 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.03758) for a snappy description of these), but there things are quite harder:

- For simplicial sets, we now have to deal with homotopy groups instead of homology, and this is after an application of $\mathrm{Ex}^\infty$, since these will likely fail to be Kan complexes in general. Moreover, it is not even clear that this would be the correct definition; maybe we [should instead just take $\pi_0$ of the iterated loop spaces at a point](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433860) (which will be just be a set in general, with no group/monoid structure); or maybe we should replace these simplicial sets by $\infty$-categories or $(\infty,2)$-categories and consider their $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ monoids, or...
- For cosimplicial sets, we reach a dead end: not only the definition is again unclear, now there isn't even (currently) a [homotopy theory of cosimplicial sets and their "homotopy cogroups"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433382/) that we could consider.

Nevertheless, there are two very interesting points here:

- First, assuming the existence of such a homotopy theory for cosimplicial sets, we could talk about things like $\pi_n\Trans^\bullet(\Delta_{(-)},D)$, which would give a second formulation (and perhaps an inequivalent one) of "higher co/limits".
- Second, an immediate group-theoretical application would be a theory of higher centers and higher characteristic classes of groups (defined as the higher co/limits of the $\Hom$ of a group, viewed as groupoid with a single object.)

Comment: (By the way, there's an analogue of all this for cyclic homology, too =)

Comment: Well, as you say, this is basically just homotopy coends…

Comment: @ZhenLin I know about the connection to homotopy co/ends, Zhen (i.e. that $\pi_n(\mathrm{HH}_\bullet(\mathcal{C};D))$ is the $\pi_n$ of the homotopy coend of $D$), but the questions I'm asking here go in a different direction than this, and most of them can't be subsumed as just being part of the theory of homotopy co/ends.

Comment: First, I'm wondering if the $\pi_n$ themselves have been studied before as the main object of interest, being thought of as "higher co/limits" of $D$. For example, has anyone tried taking the diagram $D$ computing the ring of $p$-adic integers as its limit, and then studying the homotopy (co)groups of $\mathrm{HH}^\bullet(\mathrm{Ring};D)$, relating them to number-theoretic information about $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: Or has anyone tried taking a group $G$, computing the $\pi_n$'s of the Hochschild simplicial set associated to its hom as a one-object groupoid, and then relating those (which might be viewed as higher characteristic classes of $G$) to group-theoretic information about $G$?

Comment: Second, some of the above notions aren't really reducible to homotopy co/ends; e.g. the notion of derivation between two functors above (and perhaps the de Rham cohomology theory of categories we might develop from it), the higher limits defined as the representing objects of $\pi_n(\mathrm{Trans}^\bullet(\Delta_{(-)},D))$ (where it isn't even clear what the correct notion of $\pi_n$ would be), or e.g. the whole accompanying cyclic co/homology version of all the above... How would one even define any of this in terms of homotopy coends?

Comment: @Emily: Zhen is correct- these really are homotopy ends or homotopy limits. In your "motivation" case they are homotopy ends taken in the derived category of R. The fact that the various invariants you're considering have negative homotopy groups does not take them outside the realm of higher category theory. Invariants of the sort you are considering (including higher centers, and other homotopy limits or mapping objects) are well-studied and basically always have homotopy groups in negative degrees (often they are the homotopy groups of some spectrum).

Comment: @DylanWilson I understand that some of these may be expressed as homotopy ends/limits (I don't immediately see how *all* of these are though, e.g. do you know how to express the module of derivations $\mathrm{Ker}(d^2)$ between two functors $F$ and $G$ defined above as a homotopy limit/end?), but what I'm insisting on is that this doesn't make any of these questions trivial ("this is basically just homotopy coends/colimits"), nor does it make any of these invariants any easier to compute.

Comment: I also mention these being orthogonal in a sense to higher category theory because e.g. derivations between two functors form a notion of "2-natural transformation" that is different from the usual one (and of course that usual one doesn't make sense here, as $F$ and $G$ are 1-functors)

Comment: (I have edited the question to clarify this)

Comment: I might be getting confused but it seems to me you're writing something like the following notion: given a dualizable object of any symmetric monoidal higher category and an endomorphism, we can consider its trace (Hochschild homology) and I believe there's also a notion of centralizer (Hochschild cohomology)- I haven't thought about that in that generality, but it certainly makes sense in the present context

Comment: In your setup for C a small R-linear category we can take $Ind(C)$ which is a dualizable presentable R-linear category with dual $Ind(C^{op})$. Your bimodule D defines an object of $End(Ind(C))=Ind(C)\otimes Ind(C^{op})$, and you are I believe calculating its Hochschild cohomology in this sense. It also has a trace ($HH_*$) and such traces are the subject of a very active field of research (categorical traces -- see eg papers of Xinwen Zhu applying them to number theory).